# BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler issue with utf-8

Tags: python, html, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem with the text showed in the HTML from "BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler" response. The HTML page receive a string value with utf-8 characters and presents it in a text box, but the utf-8 characters are visible.
The value is saved in xml file with the following format: `[15-09-02 10:16:45] Testing%2Bthe%2Bcomments%2Bpage`, read by python script and called in the page with the following url:

```
htt://URL/Comments?group=BLABLA&unit=YUO&info=[15-09-02 10:16:45] Testing%2Bthe%2Bcomments%2Bpage&another=
```

However, the html page show in the textbox the following text:

```
[15-09-02 10:16:45] Testing%2Bthe%2Bcomments%2Bpage
```

Without remove the special characters, I tried encode().decode() in the string and nothing works. Someone has any idea?
The code used to creates the webserver:

```
class MyHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
def do_HEAD(s):
    s.send_response(200)
    s.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
    s.end_headers()
def do_GET(s):
    """Respond to a GET request."""
    s.send_response(200)
    s.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
    s.end_headers()
    if("/Comments" in s.path):
        strServer = "http://" + HOST_NAME + ":" + str(PORT_NUMBER) + "/SaveComments";
        strUrl = s.path;
        s.wfile.write(CommentsPage.IndexPage(strUrl, strServer));
    elif("/SaveComments" in s.path):
        s.wfile.write(CommentsPage.SaveComments(s.path));
    else:
        s.wfile.write(CommentsPage.ErrorPage());
if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_class = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
    httpd = server_class((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER), MyHandler)
    print time.asctime(), "Server Starts - %s:%s" % (HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER)
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    httpd.server_close()
    print time.asctime(), "Server Stops - %s:%s" % (HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER)
```

Function that returns the html page:

```
def IndexPage(strUrl, strServer):
...
strPage = "<!DOCTYPE html><html>";
strPage = strPage + "<head><title>Match report comments.</title></head>";
strPage = strPage + "<body><form action=\"" + strServer + "\">";
strPage = strPage + "Group:<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"group\" value=\"" + arrGroupValue[1] + "\">";
strPage = strPage + "<br>Unit:<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"unit\" value=\"" + strUnit + "\">";
strPage = strPage + "<br>Information:<br><textarea rows=\"8\" cols=\"30\" name=\"info\">" + strInfo + "</textarea>";
strPage = strPage + "<br>Resp:<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"responsible\" value=\"" + strResp + "\">";
strPage = strPage + "<br><br><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"></form></body></html>";
return strPage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing whatsoever to do with UTF-8. This is not any kind of character set "encoding", but simply URL escaping.

You can unescape the data by using `urllib.parse.unquote` (Python 3) or `urllib.unquote` (Python 2).

Comment: Hi Daniel, 
I inserted the following code when the url is received: `strurlReceived = urllib.unquote(s.path);` , But doesn't works, the same problem occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Really, the solution is with `urllib.unquote`. When the url is saved in the xml file, before it must be formatted with `urllib.quote(url)` and in first time that it is read from file must be formatted with `urllib.unquote(read_url)`. However the white spaces are replaced by the "+" symbol, the function string.replace() solves this problem. Thanks for help!